# Convert query with STR_TO_DATE to BigQuery syntax

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I have query that uses the following:

```
STR_TO_DATE(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(fb.p_dataforanalytics,'$.birthday'), '%m/%d/%Y'), 
STR_TO_DATE(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(g.p_dataforanalytics,'$.birthday'), '%Y-%m-%d'),    
date_format(p_birthday, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

This syntax works in MySQL but it doesn't work in BigQuery.
I somehow needs to convert it using `PARSE_DATE`(?) but I can't find the proper syntax for this.

**EDIT:**

```
PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(fb.p_dataforanalytics,'$.birthday') ),
PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(g.p_dataforanalytics,'$.birthday')),
PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', p_birthday)
```

Dosent work.
I get:

> Invalid result from parsing function

and also
on the `p_birthday` row:

> No matching signature for function PARSE_DATE for argument types:
>   STRING, INT64. Supported signature: PARSE_DATE(STRING, STRING) at
>   [15:33]

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54541051/5221944

Answer (score 0):

Easy one, with standard SQL:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y',  '6/22/2017')


2017-06-22
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#supported-format-elements-for-date

`JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR` should work unchanged.

Comment: I know that. But this doesn't work with my query. It's not just changing the function name.

Comment: I get Invalid result from parsing function

Comment: Looking at the edited question: Now you seem to have problems parsing the JSON data. Can you paste your JSON data in a new question? Also, can you paste the value of p_birthday? Seems to be a number and not a string.

Comment: some of the data may be invalid. How can I make sure that it can be converted to date and if not simply show NULL ? Basicly to PARSE_DATE if possible and if not return NULL