# PARSE_DATE : Invalid result from parsing function BigQuery/Standard SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following code in BigQuery (standard SQL):

```
SAFE_CAST (PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d',JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(g.p_dataforanalytics,'$.birthday') ) as string)
```

This fails due to:

> Invalid result from parsing function

The problem is that I have no control of the data I get in `g.p_dataforanalytics` some of it is pure garbage and not in the right format, sometimes it's not even reasonable value.
Is there a way to define that if `PARSE_DATE()` fails it will return NULL and not throw the query out?

Basicly I'm looking for something like a try/catch in any programming language?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `SAFE.` prefix on the *parse*:

```
SAFE.PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(g.p_dataforanalytics, '$.birthday') )
```

I don't see the utility of converting this back to a string, unless you wanted a solution like this:

```
COALESCE(FORMAT('%Y-%m-%d',
                COALESCE(SAFE.PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(g.p_dataforanalytics, '$.birthday'), 
                         SAFE.PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(g.p_dataforanalytics, '$.birthday')
                        ) 

                ), JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(g.p_dataforanalytics, '$.birthday'
        )
```

That is, if the code tested different formats for the date, chose one, turned it back into YYYY-MM-DD format.  And, if none of the formats worked, then kept the original value.

Comment: The convert to string is because I COALESCE this with more fields which are STRINGS and COALESCE force to have all fields of the same type

Comment: @Luis . . . If you are not using the value as a date, why do you need to convert it to a date first?

Comment: To get it in YYYY-MM-DD   I know it's also possible using string manipulation but that seems like more coding

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and (I think) covers most of crazy variation of date representations by using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library via [BigQuery UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#including-external-libraries) with external libraries.

Note: you need to upload `moment.js` into `your_bucket` on GCS

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION PARSE_DATE_CUSTOM(format_string STRING, date_string STRING )
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
        return moment(date_string).format(format_string);
"""
OPTIONS (
    library="gs://your_bucket/moment.js"
);
SELECT 
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(g.p_dataforanalytics, '$.birthday') birthday_in_json,
  PARSE_DATE_CUSTOM('YYYY-MM-DD', JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(g.p_dataforanalytics, '$.birthday')) birthday
FROM `project.dataset.table` g
```

As you can see - there is a new custom function `PARSE_DATE_CUSTOM(format_string STRING, date_string STRING )` introduced here - which accepts any string representing date and format you want final output to be in. Supported formats are [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

You can test, play with above using dummy data as in below simplified example

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION PARSE_DATE_CUSTOM(format_string STRING, date_string STRING )
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
        return moment(date_string).format(format_string);
"""
OPTIONS (
    library="gs://your_bucket/moment.js"
);
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '{"birthday":"2000-12-31"}' p_dataforanalytics UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"birthday":"2000-15-31"}' UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"birthday":"12/31/2000"}' UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"birthday":"31 Dec 2000"}' UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"birthday":"Around 2000, Dec 31"}' 
)
SELECT 
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(g.p_dataforanalytics, '$.birthday') birthday_in_json,
  PARSE_DATE_CUSTOM('YYYY-MM-DD', JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(g.p_dataforanalytics, '$.birthday')) birthday
FROM `project.dataset.table` g
```

with result

```
Row     birthday_in_json        birthday     
1       2000-12-31              2000-12-31   
2       2000-15-31              Invalid date     
3       12/31/2000              2000-12-31   
4       31 Dec 2000             2000-12-31   
5       Around 2000, Dec 31     2000-12-31
```